# Printing a C++ array through assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, x86

Currently, I'm having a number of problems. When I debug my code, my C++ runs normally until I get to the assembly function call, which jumps to L2 in my assembly code rather than L1. I'm not sure why its doing this. On top of that, I'm trying to get the array to be printed to the screen but as of right now, I just get a huge number instead. I tried including Irvine's library and using "WriteDec" to try and print out the elements, but the library won't even be recognized.

Below is my current code in assembly to take 3 arrays from C++ code, and add them together.

```
.model flat, C
.model flat, STDCALL

.code
ASMsumarray PROC,
ptr1:PTR DWORD,     ; points to array
ptr2:PTR DWORD,     ; points to array
ptr3:PTR DWORD      ; points to array
pushad              

    mov esi,ptr2  
    mov edi,ptr3  
    mov ecx,10    

    L1:
        mov ebx,[edi]  ;mov first elem of ptr3 to ebx
        add ebx,[esi]  ;add elem from ptr2 to ebx
        mov [esi],ebx  ;mov ebx to spot in ptr2. ptr2 elem now contains sum of ptr2 and 3
        add edi,4
        add esi,4
    loop L1
        mov edi,ptr1  ;mov ptr1 to esi
        mov ecx,10    ;mov ptr2 to edi
        sub edi,40
        sub esi,40
    L2:
        mov ebx,[edi]  ;mov first elem of ptr2 to ebx
        add ebx,[esi]  ;add elem from ptr1 to ebx
        mov [esi],ebx  ;mov ebx to spot in ptr1. ptr1 elem now contains sum of ptr1 and 2
        add edi,4
        add esi,4
    loop L2

    popad               ;//pop registers off the stack
        ret
ASMsumarray ENDP
```

This is the c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int ASMsumarray(int array1[], int array2[], int array3[]);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));      //seed rand num     

    int array1[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    int array2[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    int array3[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
/*
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array1[i] = rand() % 10;
    array2[i] = rand() % 10;
    array3[i] = rand() % 10;
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    */

    //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //cout << array1[i] << endl;
    //}

    cout << "The number is " << ASMsumarray(array1, array2, array3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `sub edi,40` is wrong. You have just loaded `edi` from `ptr1` you should not subtract from it. Incidentally, it would be more readable to reload `esi` instead of subtracting too.

Comment: the title is a tiny bit misleading because they are commonly called c-arrays while c++ has a `std::array`

Comment: May I ask what's the reason you use assembly code to do this?

Comment: @user0042 lab for class. Professor only told me my incrementing was off, which was a stupid mistake, but I'm stumped here.

Comment: @Jester what do you mean by reload? I have added another ptr to edi in the second loop. Unless you mean popping it off the stack before entering the 2nd loop

Comment: You have `mov edi,ptr1` but then `sub edi,40`.That makes no sense.

Comment: @Jester If i don't include it, I get the following error "Run-Time Check error2 stack around the variable 'array1' was corrupted"

Comment: You don't include what?  I hope you deleted the `sub edi, 40`.

Answer (score 0):

> On top of that, I'm trying to get the array to be printed to the screen but as of right now, I just get a huge number instead.

Your function is supposed to return an `int`, but you're using `popad` to restore *all* registers, including the caller's value of `eax`.  So your return value is whatever garbage the caller left in `eax`.

Also, you never put a value into `eax`: the calling convention you're using expects the return value in `eax`, like almost all x86 calling conventions.

Just save/restore the call-preserved registers that you actually need to use, using `push` / `pop`.  (And use as few as possible, e.g. use `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` for your pointers and temporaries.)

---

And BTW, your C++ caller is not printing the array, it's only printing the *sum* (the function return value).  Your function's return value is a scalar.  It's not clear why you're modifying the array contents at all.

---

> When I debug my code, my C++ runs normally until I get to the assembly function call, which jumps to L2 in my assembly code rather than L1.

That makes no sense.  Make sure you set a breakpoint at the actual function entry point (which isn't L1 or L2).  Or single-step by single instructions into your function, instead of by C statements.